What is the best way to recursively run a Terminal command with a changing variable in the command?
I have a few thousand GoPro RAW images, and the best way to convert them to a workable format is to use their command line conversion tool in the following format:
$ gpr_tools -i /path/G0028513.GPR -o /path/G0028513.DNG

The filenames are sequential, so is there is a way to create a loop where I have a start and end variable that represents the first and last files (eg. 28513, and 33512), and add one to that number on each iteration to use in the two "path" sections of the command?

I don't see how this is related to your terminal. The commands are executed by the respective shell, which you have started in your terminal, but you didn't tell us which one you are using.

Ah ok, wasn't aware that I had to specify this. I'm using zsh

Well, if you want some code, we need to know which programming language  the code is supposed to be in. BTW, for a task of this complexity, if gpr-tools does not offer what you want, I don't think that you will find an existing command in your operating system (which remindes me that you also did not specify which OS you are using!) , you will have to write a small program to perform this task (say, a shell script in any shell you like, or, since you are using zsh,  a zsh function).

for i in {16243..28784}

do

  /gpr/build/source/app/gpr_tools/gpr_tools -i /path-to-GPR-files/G00$i.GPR -o /path-to-DNG-folder/G00$i.DNG

done


Change the path to gpr_tools to where you have yours located. Eg.
"/gpr/build/source/app/gpr_tools/gpr_tools"
Change the input path to where your RAW .GPR files are. I'm reading and writing to my SD card, so my path is actually "/Volumes/256GB/DCIM/GPR/"
Change the output path to where you want them saved.
Change the two numbers at the top
to represent the first file, and the last file. My first file is
G0016239.GPR, last file is G0028784.DNG. I actually changed my camera
settings mid-way through this timelapse, going from day to night, so
my files jump from 18xxx to 28xxx. But the script will just skip
all the missing numbers in between, and continue correctly when it
hits correct files.

Happy shooting!

I would check first that the input file exists, before invoking gpr_tools and - unnecessarily - provoking an error message. This should also be faster, since you create then the gpr_tools  child process only for those files, which indeed exist. However, your script does not fulfill the requirement that start and end are variable.
